# Postgresql function for checking date ranges

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure how to check for date ranges using a postgres function. What I want to do is check if a date falls within a certain range (with leeway of a week before the starting date)

So basically, I want to check if a date is between `7 days before to current date`, and if so I'll return the id of that row.

```
create or replace function eight(_day date) returns text as $$
declare
  r record;
  check alias for $1;
  startDate date;
begin
    for r in
    select * from terms
    order by starting;
  loop
    startDate := r.starting;
    if check between (..need help to create 7 days before startDate) and startDate return r.id;


end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I also have to check if the previous record's ending date collides with the startDate  - 7days. How would I check the previous record?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL checking a previous record's element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257600/postgresql-checking-a-previous-records-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use an [interval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT):

```
startDate - interval '...'
```

I won't say any more than this since you're doing homework.

Comment: i was using `if check between startDate - interval '7 days'` but I'm not sure if that works

Comment: @SNpn: Why don't you think `between startDate - interval '7 days' and startDate` works?

Comment: i wasn't sure if the `'7 days'` part would work, also could you read my edit in OP - bit stuck on how to tackle that.

Comment: Added my answer.  Just do between (startdate - 7) and startdate or the like.  Dates work with integer math, where integers represent days.

Answer (score 0):

Dates work with integer math.

startdate - 8 is equivalent to (startdate::timestamp - '8 days'::interval)::date